# How to make prepared statement with multi_query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im currently trying to post some metadata about an user to a mysql db using php and mysqli. I retrieve an array with key/value pairs corresponding to the key/value pairs they are supposesd to be stored as in the DB.

```
function insert_metadata_to_db ($user_id, $metaData) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");

    foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
        $metaDataSql .= "insert into usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) values ($user_id, '$key', '$value');";
    }

    if(!$conn->multi_query($metaDataSql)) {
        echo("Failed to execute the queries." . $conn->error);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

My next step is to be secure from SQL injections. I have tried, and failed, making this method above with prepared statements. This was my attempt:

```
function insert_metadata_to_db ($user_id, $metaData) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");

    foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
        $metaDataSql .= $conn->prepare("insert into usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) values (?, '?', '?');");
        $metaDataSql->bind_param("iss", $user_id, $key, $value);
    }

    if(!$conn->multi_query($metaDataSql)) {
        echo("Failed to execute the queries." . $conn->error);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Is it even possible to do it this way? if not - what would be the best way to handle multiple inserts to a database while staying secure from SQL injections.

Comment: Why multiquery? Just do as many queries as you have records. Or even `INSERT INTO VALUES (), (), ()`. Also placeholders __must not__ be in quotes, reread a manual.

Comment: I wanted to make it a multiquery so that i avoid making 10+ seperate insert queries to the database. I was thinking this would improve the performance/reduce overhead. 
Also makes it easier to add more metadata in the future, without having to edit this method - and only edit the array.

Comment: You still have 10+ queries but now only in one string, they still will be performed one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't prepare a `mysqli::multi_query` - but using a prepared statement, you can iterate over the same query, with just with different values. This is more optimized than iterating over and running a standard `query()`.

`mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` is by reference, so you just have to bind it once, and execute it for each iteration.

```
function insert_metadata_to_db ($user_id, $metaData) {
    $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $user_id, $key, $value);
    foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
```

You can also build up a single query if you just want to execute it once. This is not necessarily much faster than the above, but can be slightly faster. Use the unpacking-operator (or "splat operator") `...` to unpack the entire array where you bind it.

```
function insert_metadata_to_db ($user_id, $metaData) {
    $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test");
    $query = "INSERT INTO usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ";
    $data = [];

    // Build the query, by appending values and inserting into the $data array
    foreach($metaData as $key => $value) {
        $query .= "(?, ?, ?), ";
        $data[] = $user_id;
        $data[] = $key;
        $data[] = $value;
    }

    // Trim away trailing comma
    $query = rtrim($query, ",");

    // If there are any data to bind, we can execute the query
    if (count($data)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("iss", count($metaData)), ...$data);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

**Sidenote**
Its usually a very bad idea to initialize a connection within a function! You should instead pass a global connection as a parameter to the function. Right now, a new connection is established every time you use that function.

Comment: I prefer your first approach! Although the second will possibly be marginally faster the first is so much easier to comprehend.

Comment: thank you. your first approach was exactly what i was looking for. And ill get right on the connection

Comment: @Nick I agree! I would prefer the first solution too, but it was merely to show that its possible with a single query (which, as stated, might not necessarily be much better than the first...).

Comment: I would also add that in case there are many inserts, it's worth to wrap them in a transaction. could greatly improve the performance.

Comment: If i may return to the sidenote @Qirel I have done some research about best practices for establishing a database connection. Afaik your suggestion is dependency injection which seems like the best option, but where do u reckon i should create the global connection? Im having difficulties researching it, since every resource i find is written in oop, rather than prodedural php.

Comment: If its OOP or procedural MySQLi doesn't matter. It depends somewhat on how you've made your application, but generally, if there's an autoloader of sorts, you'd add it so it's autoloaded along with other (possible) libraries and global declarations. It should be in the global scope, then pass it down into the functions where you need it. That way, you just make 1 connection for each request.